# Getting this error when i run npm intall firebase ,how do i fix

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to install firebase in my React project when I run `npm i firebase` I get this error

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...","@firebase/messagin'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-18T12_47_18_681Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

try running
`npm cache clean --force` and then `npm i firebase` again.

Comment: after run `npm cache clean --force` and  `npm i firebase` i get this errot `npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase%2fauth (over 30000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-18T13_40_46_510Z-debug.log`